# Bind paired data in object to another element outside ng-repeat - angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind

I have this array of objects that I need to work with:

```
$scope.pdfs = [
  { "pdf_title": "Corporate Hire", "attached_file": "http://file1.jpg"},
  { "pdf_title": "Wedding Hire", "attached_file": "http://file2.jpg"},
  { "pdf_title": "Filming Hire", "attached_file": "http://file3.jpg"}
];
```

The pdf_file value is ng-repeated in li's.

What I want to do is if that li is clicked, to push its paired to another div, say the src for an href.

Here are my workings, but not quite correct:

**Controller function:**

```
$scope.bindWithFile = function(value) {
            var currentValue = $scope.corpResult = value;

        // pdfs support
        var pdfs = $scope.pdfs;

        for (var i = pdfs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (currentValue == hasOwnProperty(key[pdfs])) {
                value[pdfs] = $scope.corpLinkHref;
            }
        };
```

**Markup:**

```
<div class="w-12" ng-controller="corpHireController">
    <div class="c-6-set">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="pdf in pdfs" class="col-7 link link-inherit" ng-click="bindWithFile(pdf.pdf_title)">{{::pdf.pdf_title}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="c-6-set">
        <div class="w-12">
            <i class="fs-4 col-7 icon icon-pdf"></i>
        </div>
        <span class="col-7 h4" ng-bind="corpResult"></span>
        <button ng-href="{{::corpLinkHref}}" class="button green2-button smaller-letters full-width">Download</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What is needed:**
Clicking on the titles on the left, binds the pdf_title under the pdf icon and binds the attached_file to the button's href

[image: Clicking on the titles on the left, binds the pdf_title under the pdf icon and binds the attached_file to the button's href]

Comment: Can you explain more in depth what you are trying to accomplish? It's hard to understand your purpose just by one sentence. It seems there is a logical problem.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin I have added an image and a 'what is needed' to explain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the `title` of the selected pdf, why not passing the whole object. This way you don't have to performance any `find` or `search` function.

#### Markup:

```
<div class="w-12" ng-controller="corpHireController">
  <div class="c-6-set">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="pdf in pdfs" class="col-7 link link-inherit" 
          ng-click="bindWithFile(pdf)">
        {{::pdf.pdf_title}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="c-6-set">
    <div class="w-12">
      <i class="fs-4 col-7 icon icon-pdf"></i>
    </div>
    <span class="col-7 h4" ng-bind="corpResult"></span>
    <button ng-href="{{::corpLinkHref}}" 
            class="button green2-button smaller-letters full-width">
      Download
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
$scope.bindWithFile = function(selectedPdf) {
  $scope.corpResult = selectedPdf.pdf_title;
  $scope.corpLinkHref = selectedPdf.attached_file;
}
```